# NPM version is not being show

Tags: node.js, npm-install, failed-installation, npm-start

After the installation of Nodejs(20.9.0) on my laptop, whenever I am checking for node version in my cmd it shows the correct version but on checking for the npm version, it is throwing an error which i am not able to solve.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.9.0
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Node.js v20.9.0
How do it deal with it?

1. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the whole of Node but it doesn't seem to work.
2. I tried some other methods suggested by ChatGPT, but they also don't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check your system variables for node path. This normally happens due to the wrong path for node in system variables.
In my case, I was pointing to:**

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin

**and the path it should ideally be pointing is to :**

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

**Fixing this system variable path resolved the issue for me.**

If the above did not work try finding your nodejs and setting this in Adminstratpr Terminal like below:

```
SET PATH=C:\<you-nodejs-path>\Nodejs;%PATH%
```